# How do I use testfor to testfor players nearby?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use a command block to testfor a player within three blocks of it. It should then activate a comparator. I followed the basic syntax, typing `testfor @a [r=3]`. However, when I ran it, it said that that was the wrong way to syntax it. I followed its tips, and got `testfor @a {r:3}` but then no matter what I tried, the comparator wouldn't turn on. Frustrated, I typed `/testfor` in the chat to see the proper syntax. It said `testfor <player> [datatag]` but when I used that syntax earlier, it gave me a syntax error! I went back and forth between them, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in the selector.

```
testfor @a[r=3]
```

No space between @a and [r=3].

Just to note it, the comparator output signal strength will be equal to the amount of players it finds in that radius.

Answer (score 0):

The selector must have no space in between them.

If you do `/testfor @a [r=3]` the `[r=3]` is seen as a value and thus breaks as it cant use this as a Value. However, doing `/testfor @a[r=3]` means selector.

The default setup for commands is `/"Command"->"target+selector"->"value"`.
If you want it to Active for anyone place a repeater right after the comparator